# How can I get output from subprocess.check_output if the subprocess is a java program(with Command-line arguments)?

Tags: java, python, subprocess, command-line-arguments

I have the following java code: (HelloWorld.class is in bin folder):

```
package Hello;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World" + args[1]);
    }
}
```

I want to call this java code from a python script and pass some command-line arguments to it.

So my python code is:

```
cmd = ["java","-classpath","bin/","Hello.HelloWorld","arguement1","arguement2"]
try:
    print subprocess.check_output(cmd,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except: subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print ('calling '+ ' '.join(cmd) +' failed\n')
```

If I run this code, I will get the no output from java code, and also get output "calling java -classpath bin/ Hello.HelloWorld arguement1 arguement2 failed".

But if I run:

```
java -classpath bin/ Hello.HelloWorld arguement1 arguement2
```

in terminal, the java code will print the string.

So where is wrong of my python code?

Comment: are you sure calling the command is starting where you think it does? try using an absolute path for your bin directory

Comment: the python script is under the bin's parent's directory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the output because both stdout and stderr are captured by `check_output(stderr=STDOUT)` and `java` exits with a non-zero exit status that leads to the exception and that is why you see ".. failed" message.

To get subprocess' output in the exception handler `except CalledProcessErrror as e:`, access `e.output` attribute.

If you don't need to capture the output then just call `call()` instead:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```